# How to create extension in PostgreSQL db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I want to create an extension, called `UNACCENT`, when I create my database.

I know this can be achieved with the database command:

```
CREATE EXTENSION UNACCENT
```

However, I don't know where to put this. My db is PostgreSQL, and I am  working on a Rails application.

Comment: Use correct grammar and capitalisation. Format code for easier readability.

Also, check what tags actually mean on this site; don't just blindly assume the keywords are relevant to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any PostgreSQL client, for example, default psql to connect to your database and you should be able to run CREATE EXTENSION with it if your user has enough privileges.